# Any way to determine no of text lines in image?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

Actually, I have to find no of text lines in the given image For e.g. If I am having two images

```
from PIL import ImageGrab
img1=ImageGrab.grab([0,0,200,80])
img2=ImageGrab.grab([300,0,500,80])
```

[image: img1]
[image: img2]

first one is img1
and second one is img2

How can I get the number of text lines in an image, so that it outputs 5 for img1, and 4 for img2?

Comment: You could try a Web service, such as Microsoft's Computer Vision (part of Azure Cognitive Services) or Google Cloud Vision.

Comment: You can ocr the image using tesseract and then count the lines. Although the quality of image seems to be low. OpenCV also have Text Detection in 3.0

Comment: tesseract is giving error

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do this without OCR-ing the text, the typical approach, is to determine for each line in the image if it has one or more than one color.

The lines with one color can be assumed to be background any transition from more than one color to a single color is the "bottom" line of a text row. Count those transitions and you'll have the number of lines of text in an image.

This assumes:

- characters of one line do no extend completely to the bottom of the cell they are drawn in (that would mean there might never be an empty line if the top line has a `g` and the bottom one an `f` - or similar configurations)
- there is only text and not pictures (as in you samples).

Comment: how can I get a single line iteratively ? and How can i get colors in that line.
for a pil image  x I have found a method x.getcolors but how can I divide a pil image into lines

Comment: IIRC there is no such function to get a whole line. You'll have to iterate over the height and check the pixels (of course only until you get a difference).

Answer (score 0):

You can find the number of lines in a text image using open cv :

```
grayscale = cv2.cvtColor(your_text_image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

# converting to binary image
_, binary = cv2.threshold(gray, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_OTSU)

# inverting to have white text on black background
binary = 255 - binary

# calculation y axis histogram
hist = cv2.reduce(binary, 1, cv2.REDUCE_AVG).reshape(-1)

# append every y position corresponding to a bottom of text line
lines = []
for y in range(h - 1):
   if hist[y + 1] <= 2 < hist[y]:
        lines.append(y)

number_of_lines = len(lines)
```

Answer (score 0):

1. First Threshold the image.
2. Calculate mean pixel value of horizontally(top to bottom).
3. After getting all values find out the transitions/significant gap. If there is significant gap between black pixel then(you need to decide white pixel threshold: how many number of white pixels between two line).
4. Number of continuous black pixel cluster is your answer.